# How to test a site for different locations

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How can i do a performance testing of a website for different locations in testing environment with jmeter.like if we have website for uk,USA and Canada and hosted on respective countries.If I am in UK,how can I test it for USA and Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter can be run in [distributed clustered mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so you can have load generators residing in different world ends. For instance [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) provides option of launching virtual machines instances in different geographic regions, micro instances are [free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)

As far as I'm aware [Blazemeter Cloud](http://blazemeter.com/) offers geo-distributed load testing and it's free for up to 50 concurrent virtual users.

Comment: But how can i test my application with blaze meter which is in test environment,do i need to specify the local network info somewhere?

Comment: I think that your IT should be able to temporary open firewall connection for certain IP addresses on specific port or use VPN or whatever. I suggest contacting their support for details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the proxy services. There are many services that will allow to your local machine "be" in the required country. One of the options is [Hola](https://hola.org/).

Comment: but how can i use Hola on my linux servers to execute script.

Comment: Also want to mention that website is not in production environment yet,it is still in testing phase

Comment: For the linux machine you can consider  [GeoEdge](http://www.geoedge.com/) a provider of Proxy services for various countries through Browser Extension/ Add On